# How to use guest network on host using VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I need to use a VPN which only works under Windows. However, I would like to keep working with Linux as I feel more comfortable with it. So I was wondering if there is any chance I can start a VirtualBox instance with a Windows environment, start the VPN and that my host network is tunneled through the guess network, so I can access the VPN resources.

Thanks

Comment: Most VPN software disable every local network for security reasons. If this is also the case in your VPN configuration the network connection between the Windows host and the Linux guest will be impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. You will have to enable “bridging mode” and enable privileges on VirtualBox.

But be careful: some VPNs clients are blocking local network traffic and route everithing inside the VPN.